# Objectmapper.readerforupdating not working for nested objects

Tags: java, nested-lists, json-deserialization, objectmapper, json-view

I have a problem with Objectmapper.readerforupdating using different write permissions with the help of views, it is working fine on main entity but not on nested objects. I have the following example:

```
public class A {

    @JsonView(value={WritePermission.Admin})
    private String name;
    
    @JsonView(value={WritePermission.User})
    private String property;
    
    @JsonView(value={WritePermission.User})
    private List<B> list;
}

public class B {
    @JsonView(value={WritePermission.Admin})
    private String name;
    
    @JsonView(value={WritePermission.User})
    private String property;
    
}

public class WritePermission {
    public WritePermission() {
    }
   
     public static class Admin extends WritePermission.User {
        public Admin() {
        }
    }

    public static class User {
        public User() {
        }
    }
}
```

For deserialization I use this: objectMapper.readerForUpdating(initialEntityOfAClass).withView(WritePermission.User.class).forType(A.class).readValue(json)
and also tried with this but I get the same result:
ObjectReader objectReader = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(initialEntityOfAClass);

When I want to deserialize a json with a User write role, I would like to overwrite only the attributes where I have permission, this works fine for attributes from class A (in the name attribute remains the old value cuz I do not have the rights to update, property attribute is updated) but it does not work for the list of B items - instead of changing the B objects just like for A (name remains old value, property is updated from json) creates new objects for the list of B and name remains null because as a User I do not have a permission to write values to name attribute. If I set @JsonMerge on the B list, instead of merge I am getting the old (the ones where the name is already set but property not changed) and the newly created objects (the ones where the property changed but with name=null) in one list... Can anyone help me here, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here. The first problem is based in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty` not reading the property value if a read method is present. So the deserialization for nested objects always starts with a `null` value and therefore constructs a new instance first.

The other problem is handling the collection elements that are already part of the list.

To solve the first problem do the following:

- create an `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty` implementation that does read the property value if a read method is present and then use that value as the basis for deserialization:

```
public class DeepUpdatingMethodProperty extends SettableBeanProperty {

    private final MethodProperty delegate;
    private final Method propertyReader;

    public DeepUpdatingMethodProperty(MethodProperty src, Method propertyReader) {
        super(src);
        this.delegate = src;
        this.propertyReader = propertyReader;
    }

    @Override
    public SettableBeanProperty withValueDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> deser) {
        return new DeepUpdatingMethodProperty((MethodProperty) delegate.withValueDeserializer(deser), propertyReader);
    }

    @Override
    public SettableBeanProperty withName(PropertyName newName) {
        return new DeepUpdatingMethodProperty((MethodProperty) delegate.withName(newName), propertyReader);
    }

    @Override
    public SettableBeanProperty withNullProvider(NullValueProvider nva) {
        return new DeepUpdatingMethodProperty((MethodProperty) delegate.withNullProvider(nva), propertyReader);
    }

    @Override
    public AnnotatedMember getMember() {
        return delegate.getMember();
    }

    @Override
    public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> acls) {
        return delegate.getAnnotation(acls);
    }

    @Override
    public void deserializeAndSet(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object instance) throws IOException {
        deserializeSetAndReturn(p, ctxt, instance);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserializeSetAndReturn(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object instance)
            throws IOException {
        if (instance != null && !p.hasToken(JsonToken.VALUE_NULL)) {
            Object readValue;
            try {
                readValue = readValueFromInstance(instance);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                _throwAsIOE(p, e, instance);
                return instance;
            }
            if (readValue != null) {
                return deepUpdateDeserializeSetAndReturn(p, ctxt, instance, readValue);
            }
        }
        return delegate.deserializeSetAndReturn(p, ctxt, instance);
    }

    private Object deepUpdateDeserializeSetAndReturn(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object instance,
            Object readValue) throws IOException, JacksonException, JsonMappingException {
        Object value;
        if (_valueTypeDeserializer == null) {
            value = _valueDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt, readValue);
            if (value == null) {
                if (NullsConstantProvider.isSkipper(_nullProvider)) {
                    return instance;
                }
                value = _nullProvider.getNullValue(ctxt);
            }
        } else {
            value = _valueDeserializer.deserializeWithType(p, ctxt, _valueTypeDeserializer, readValue);
        }
        return setAndReturn(instance, value);
    }

    private Object readValueFromInstance(Object instance)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        return propertyReader.invoke(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(Object instance, Object value) throws IOException {
        delegate.set(instance, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object setAndReturn(Object instance, Object value) throws IOException {
        return delegate.setAndReturn(instance, value);
    }
}
```

- Use a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier` to modify the properties of a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer` to use the above implementation if a property read method is present

```
public class DeepUpdatingDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {
    
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
            JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        if(deserializer instanceof BeanDeserializer beanDeserializer) {
            enableDeepUpdateForReadableProperties(beanDesc, beanDeserializer);
        }
        return deserializer;
    }

    private void enableDeepUpdateForReadableProperties(BeanDescription beanDesc, BeanDeserializer beanDeserializer) {
        Iterator<SettableBeanProperty> iter = beanDeserializer.properties();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            SettableBeanProperty property = iter.next();
            if (property instanceof MethodProperty methodProperty) {
                Method propertyReader = getPropertyReader(methodProperty, beanDesc);
                if (propertyReader != null) {
                    DeepUpdatingMethodProperty adoptedProperty = new DeepUpdatingMethodProperty(methodProperty, propertyReader);
                    beanDeserializer.replaceProperty(methodProperty, adoptedProperty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Method getPropertyReader(MethodProperty src, BeanDescription beanDesc) {
        BeanInfo beanInfo;
        Class<?> propertyRawClass = beanDesc.getBeanClass();
        try {
            beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(propertyRawClass);
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(MessageFormat.format("Could not introspect {0}.", propertyRawClass), e);
        }
        return Arrays.asList(beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()).stream()
                .filter(e -> Objects.equals(src.getName(), e.getName())).map(PropertyDescriptor::getReadMethod)
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Note that this will only work for method properties and not for constructor properties for example.

Regarding the second problem I changed collection deserialization to something different so that instead of a plain json representation I have something like this to deserialize the collection from:

```
{
    "someListProperty": {
        "collectionModifications": [{
                "_type": "removeIf",
                "predicate": {
                    "_type": "hasPropertyWithValue",
                    "property": "foo",
                    "valueMatcher": {
                        "_type": "or",
                        "matchers": [{
                                "_type": "equalTo",
                                "value": "foobar"
                            }, {
                                "_type": "startsWith",
                                "prefix": "foo."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "_type": "add",
                "elements": [{
                        "foo": "bar"
                    }, {
                        "foo": "baz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The above example will remove values with property `foo` equal to `foobar` or starting with `foo.` from the list first and then add the values specified in `elements`. You could implement your own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer` based on your needs. However I found that working with maps instead of lists is easier in such cases but I hadn't such a use case in my example yet. In your example you could use the `name` property as the map key.